# How to close the AJAX update panel after the download is complete in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to incorporate a processing or loading icon so that when users create and download a PDF file the processing/loading gif pops up letting the user know that their request is processing. I am using an AJAX update panel with an AJAX update progress to display the processing icon but after the process is finished the update panel with the processing div does not hide. I've tested this out on a test page and with a method that has a Thread.Sleep() set for 2 seconds and it works, but not for the main portion of the page with the long process.

[Progress panel stil visible after download is complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgKHD.png)

AJAX:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
            <asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" CssClass="alert-warning" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ProcessPanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Download" runat="server" CssClass="btn-primary" Text="Download Images" ToolTip="Downloads the current list of images." OnClick="DownloadPDF_Click"/>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Download" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <br />
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="ProcessPanel">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div id="progress" class="loading" style="align-content:center;">
                    Processing your request, Please wait. <br />
                    <br />
                    <img src="../Images/loader.gif" alt="" />
                </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>  
            <br />
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript>
     window.onsubmit = function () {
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            var updateProgress = $find("<%= UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>");
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                updateProgress.set_visible(true);
            }, 10);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I'm working off an example that I found [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Show-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdateProgress-with-UpdatePanel-PostBackTrigger.aspx).

So in the back-end of the Web app, I have code that creates a text file of a list of image paths that then is used by Irfanview to put all of those images into a pdf which is then downloaded to the user. All of which is done in one method down below.

```
protected void CreatePDF()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Tried 
            RetrieveSecondaryInformation();
            ImageFile_Creation();
            int count = 0;
            string fileName, i_viewLocaton, pdfName, _filePath;
            string pdfPath = @"C:\Some_Long_File_Path\ImageResources\"; // Development Path to the PDF folder Location
            fileName = imageListName;
            i_viewLocaton = @"C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe";
            pdfName = SetPDFName();
            if (fileName != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Download.Text = "Processing";
                    string folderPath = @"C:\Another_Long_File_Path\ImageResources\"; // Development path to where the file will be written to
                    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath)) // Checks if the directory exists and if not then create it.
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName))) // Stream writer object is used to create the txt file
                    {
                        foreach (string line in @ImageList) // Goes thru each item in Array and writes each string on a new line
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("C:\\Long_File_Path\\" + line); // Development
                        }
                    }
                    lblInfo.Text = "Text file written successfully";
                    _filePath = @"C:\Another_Long_File_Path\ImageResources\"; // Development
                    fileName = _filePath + fileName;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { lblInfo.Text = "An error has occured while trying to create the image list: " + ex.Message + dataTable.Columns.ToString(); }
                finally 
                { 
                    lblInfo.Visible = true;
                } 
            }
            else { lblInfo.Text += "\nStopped the process"; } /* End of Secton 1 of 3 */
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (Process process = new Process()) // Creates a new process Object.
                    {
                        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; // Keeps the cmd shell window from popping up when the batch file is executed.
                        process.StartInfo.FileName = "IDS-Irfanview2.bat"; // Name of the batch file to be executed
                        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Another_Long_File_Path\ImageResources\"; // Development Location of the batch file
                        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + i_viewLocaton + "\"" + " " + "\"" + pdfName + "\"" + " " + "\"" + fileName + "\"" + " " + "/one" + " " + "/killmesoftly";
                        process.Start(); // Executes the batch file.
                        process.WaitForExit();
                    }                   
                    while (!File.Exists(pdfPath + pdfName)) // Loop that keeps running to check if the specific file exists. If not it continues to loop and wait 1 sec
                                                  // If it does exist it breaks the loop and moves to next section. Will need to set a delay limit (like 10s) 
                                                  // to break the loop.
                    { // Can be condensed down with process.WaitForExit(). On To Do list
                        lblInfo.Text = "Awaiting for file to be created";
                        if (File.Exists(pdfPath + pdfName))
                        {
                            lblInfo.CssClass = "label-success";
                            lblInfo.Text = "PDF ready for download";
                            break;
                        }
                        count += 1000;
                        if (count == 10000) { lblInfo.Text = "Could not find file"; break; }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblInfo.Text = "An error has occured during pdf creation: " + ex.Message;
                }
            } /* End of Secton 2 of 3 */
            if (File.Exists(pdfPath + pdfName))
            { // Checks to see if the file exists and if so start the download process
                try
                {
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfName);
                    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/ImageResources/" + pdfName));
                    Response.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    UpdateProgress1.Visible = false;
                    lblInfo.Text = "An error occured while trying to download the pdf" + ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    UpdateProgress1.Visible = false;
                }
            } /* End of Secton 3 of 3 */
            
            UpdateProgress1.Visible = false;
        } // End of PDF process
```

The On_Click method

```
protected void DownloadPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            CreatePDF();
            UpdateProgress1.Visible = false;
        }
```

So some of the things that I've tried was to manually set the update panel to not visible which didn't work, Use another On_Click method that would then call this method and then after it was completed, then set the visibility of the update panel to false which also didn't work. I've tried to look up other ways to try and solve this issue but so far I have not had much luck.

Comment: A good way of controlling what happens before and after postbacks with 'asp.net ajax' is by using the `page request manager`. Search for that term and/or `prm` and/or `prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);`. No threading required.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into prm and see what I can find out.